# Sorting vector of vectors without comparator or lambda function?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, lambda, comparator

Today I came across some C++ code which I thought was not going to compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> vectorOfVectors = { { 2, 3, 5 }, { 1, 2, 3 } };

    sort(vectorOfVectors.begin(), vectorOfVectors.end());

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, there is no default comparator in C++ for vectors of ints, so one would have to implement a custom comparator or lambda function in order to pass it to the sort() function.

However, the fact that this code compiled made me want to ask this question; is there a default comparator for vectors of ints? Is there one for floats, doubles, and so on? Or does the compiler automatically generate it? It should be noted that this way of sorting a vector of vectors is nowhere to be found online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there is a default comparator of vector of anything, as long as the "anything" itself is comparable.  So `vector<anything>` becomes comparable. And since this is comparable, `vector<vector<anything>>` must be comparable as well.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: "As far as I know, there is no default comparator in C++ for vectors" you know wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From cppreference on [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), for the overload `void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );` :

> 1) Elements are compared using `operator<`.

`std::vector<T>` provides [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp). Its behavior is :

> Compares the contents of `lhs` and `rhs` lexicographically. The comparison is performed by a function equivalent to std::lexicographical_compare.

The behavior of the overload of [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) that doesn't take a comparator is :

> 1) Elements are compared using `operator<`.

So as long as the type `T` in `std::vector<T>` is comparable with `operator<` then `std::vector<T>` can be compared with `operator<` and is thus compatible with `std::sort`. Since `int` is comparable with `operator<`, so is `std::vector<int>` and therefore so is `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Each of those types will work with `std::sort` without an explicit comparator.

Answer (score 7):

> As far as I know, there is no default comparator in C++ for vectors ...

There are defined comparison operators for `vector`s:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

`std::vector` has defined operators `== != < <= > >=`.

Since it is a template class, you do not need to define `operator<` for every possible type that a `vector` can hold. If the type meets [LessThanComparable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable) requirements, it will be generated.

As `int` can obviously be compared with `<`, `vector<int>` will have `operator<` generated for it.